# DIstribute points on Simulated Cloth?

Tags: physics, geometry-nodes, cloth-simulation

Is there a way to make a geometry nodes point instance work properly with cloth?
In my test it seems to work but the points randomly appear and disappear.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The points disappear because the shape of faces change during the cloth simulation.

To solve this, you will need to generate points with the faces in their original position and then set the points position to the deformed position.

For that we will need two Geometry Nodes modifiers.

The first, before the Cloth modifier, will store the original position and output it as an attribute:

[image]

The last, after the Cloth modifier, will capture the deformed position, set the position to the original from an input attribute, and then generate the points and set their position to the captured deformed position:

[image]

This works because when distributing points, the captured vector field will be interpolated like the current position of vertices.

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!